# UNITY2D: How do I destroy previous object with Singleton Pattern?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working on a project. It includes two scenes:Maingame and ShopScene. Firstly, I run the Maingame, there is a chronometer and I earn money. At the end of the day, ShopScene opens. I spend my money in ShopScene. Then I click exit button and Maingame opens again. I used Dont Destroy Objects and Singleton Pattern. However, my problem is, at first, day is 1. I earn some money. I spend some of it in ShopScene. In here, day is 2 because first day is over. Again, I come to Maingame scene, but day becomes 1 again. Aso my money becomes 0. I thought that my Singleton pattern destroys my new canvas. However, I want that my Singleton Pattern destroy previous canvas. How can I do that?
My codes are here.

```
public class EarnMoney : MonoBehaviour
{
    private static EarnMoney instance;
    private int score;
    public Button moneyBarButton;
    public GameObject canvas;
    public int money;
    private GameObject[] boxCountArray;
  
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Awake()
    {
        canvas = (GameObject.Find("DontDestroyCanvas"));
      //  DontDestroyOnLoad(canvas);
        if (instance == null)
        {
            instance = this;
            DontDestroyOnLoad(canvas);
        }
        else if (instance != this) {
            Destroy(canvas);
        }
            

   
    }
    void Start()
    {
      //  moneyBarButton = GameObject.Find("MoneyBar").GetComponent<Button>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        SceneManager.SetActiveScene(SceneManager.GetSceneByName("Maingame"));
        PlayerPrefs.GetInt("money");
        moneyBarButton.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text = Convert.ToString(money);
        score = money / 10;
        boxCountArray = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Box");
       // control();
        score =(boxCountArray.Length - 1);//score artışı
        money = (boxCountArray.Length - 1) * 10;
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("money", money);
    }
}
```

```
public class ShopManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update

    public Button itemBuyButton; //Almak istediğim itemin butonu.
    public Button moneyBar; //Para kutucuğu
    int price; //İslem yapabilmek için para kutucuğumdaki text i double a çeviricem. Bu değişken onu tutmak için.
    public Transform floatingText; //item aldığımda aldığım itemin fiyatının ekranda çıkmasını temsil eden object
    public Transform infoAboutShop; // item aldığımda itemden kaç tane aldığımı ekrana yazdıran object.
    public GameObject canvas;
   


    int n = 0;

 
    void Start()
    {
    price = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("money");

   moneyBar = GameObject.Find("MoneyBar").GetComponent<Button>();
      
    } 

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        //Butonların interaktifliği sürekli kontrol edilsin istediğimden ilgili methodu update metodumda çağırıyorum.
        
        buttonInteractable();
  PlayerPrefs.SetInt("money", price);
        moneyBar.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text = Convert.ToString(price);
    }

    public void buy()
    {
        //floatingText objemin TextMesh componentine ilgili itemin fiyatını atıyorum.
        floatingText.GetComponent<TextMesh>().text = itemBuyButton.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text;
        /*
        *Instantiate metodu clone yaratmaya yarıyor. floatingText objemden clone yaratıcam. Clonenun yaratılmasını istediğim yeri tıkladığım yer olarak belirttim.
        *Quaternion identity ise rotation olmadan ilgili objenin clonelamasını sağlıyor. Bu cloneun TextMesh componentine de aynı şekilde ilgili itemin fiyatını atıyorum.
        * Bu işlemleri buy metodunun içinde yapmamın nedeni de floatingText lerin item satın alındığında oluşacak olması.
        */
        Instantiate(floatingText, new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, Input.mousePosition.z), Quaternion.identity).GetComponent<TextMesh>().text = itemBuyButton.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text;


        //Para kutucuk butonumun text componentini double a çevirip yukarıda oluşturduğum moneyBarPrice değişkenine atıyorum. İşlemleri bu değişken üzerinden yapacağım.
        price = Convert.ToInt32(moneyBar.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text);

        //Butonun text componentine ulaşıp aynı şekilde o text i de kıyaslama yapabilmek için double a çeviriyorum.
        if (price >= (Convert.ToDouble(itemBuyButton.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text)))

        {
            // item aldıktan sonra itemin fiyatını total fiyatımdan düşüyorum.  
            price -= (Convert.ToInt32(itemBuyButton.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text));
            // kalan fiyatımı string e çevirip para kutucuğuma yazıyorum.
            moneyBar.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text = Convert.ToString(price);


            //infoAboutShop objemin TextMesh componentine ilgili itemin adını ve sayısını atıyorum.
            infoAboutShop.GetComponent<TextMesh>().text = Convert.ToString(n + 1) + " " + itemBuyButton.name;
            //floatingText teki mantıkla infoAboutShop objelerimi (200,200) konumunda clonelayıp ilgili nesnenin adı ve sayısını atıyorum.
            Instantiate(infoAboutShop, new Vector2(200, 200), Quaternion.identity).GetComponent<TextMesh>().text = infoAboutShop.GetComponent<TextMesh>().text;
            //her çağırıldığında ilgili objenin sayısını 1 artırıyorum.
            n += 1;

        }
        else
        {
            // eğer iteme tıkladıktan sonra param tıkladığım itemi almaya yetmiyorsa itemin aktifliği engelleniyor.
            itemBuyButton.interactable = false;
        }

    }

    void buttonInteractable()
    {
        price= Convert.ToInt32(moneyBar.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text);
       // Debug.Log(price);
        //Butonun text componentine ulaşıp aynı şekilde o text i de kıyaslama yapabilmek için double a çeviriyorum.
        if (price >= (Convert.ToDouble(itemBuyButton.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text)))

        {
            itemBuyButton.interactable = true; // Eğer  start butonu aktif eğilse ve param almak istediğim itemden fazlaysa butonun aktifliği devam eder.
        }
        else
        {
            itemBuyButton.interactable = false; //  param tıkladığım itemi almaya yetmiyorsa itemin aktifliği engelleniyor.
        }
    }


   
}
```

```
public class closedButton : MonoBehaviour
{
    Scene scene;
  public Button moneyBar;
   
    

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
    public void ExitShop()
    {
        SceneManager.GetActiveScene();

        SceneManager.LoadScene(0);




    }
}
```

Comment: I can't really follow it. I can't tell which class in all of that is a singleton. But it's very likely that the answer is just not to use a singleton. Unless there's an overwhelming reason why it has to be a singleton then it's probably not helpful. If it's not your class and you can't control it, then it might be a singleton to prevent you from doing whatever you're trying to do.

Comment: @Scott Hannen in EarnMoney class, Awake method  is Singleton. Am I wrong? If i dont use singleton, in Maingame scene, my canvases duplicated. Triple... and so on

Comment: A singleton is something entirely different. A method can't be a singleton. Whatever is happening with that static `instance` and comparing it to `this` looks really hard to follow. If you have multiple instances of that class they could both be overwriting that static field. That looks like trouble. It's the sort of thing that no one can really keep track of in their head, which means the code will behave in ways that are hard to predict.

Comment: Maybe where it says `Destroy(canvas)` also put `Destroy(gameObject)` below it?

Comment: @ScottHannen, I saw some similar code in a Unity Live stream where they talk about data persistence. From what I can tell, the code makes EarnMoney a singleton class, so there's only one EarnMoney. But unless EarnMoney is attached to Canvas, the code won't do much.

Comment: Example [here](https://github.com/Kettle3D/Kettle3D/blob/C%23/game/Assets/Scripts/LevelManagement.cs#L15).

Comment: This may not be very good advice, but is it possible to have the canvas not a singleton, but in all the scenes? Or does the object attached to it have important data?

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to happen when the scene loads, don't use awake. Instead use OnSceneLoaded.

```
void OnSceneLoaded(Scene scene, LoadSceneMode mode)
{
    if (string.equal(scene.name, "ShopScene")){
        // Do whatever you want here when the scene loads
        Destroy(canvas)
    }
}
```